# How to adjust the column width manually using apache poi

Tags: apache-poi

I am using apache poi to generate excel file.When i used sheet.autoSizeColumn(column no) its really effecting performance when generating the report.Is there a way that i can manually adjust the column width for specific fields?

Comment: For Excel in general [Sheet.setColumnWidth](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setColumnWidth-int-int-). Or especially for `XSSFSheet` [XSSFSheet.getColumnHelper](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#getColumnHelper--) -> [ColumnHelper.setColWidth](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/helpers/ColumnHelper.html#setColWidth-long-double-).

Comment: Have you made sure you only auto-size at the end? And what about just calling [setColumnWidth](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setColumnWidth-int-int-)?